# LTE data link security and integrity

Tags: encryption

I am studying LTE data link security features and have a few questions.
As I understand there are 3 choices for ciphering algorithms 128-EIA1/2/3 and 3 for integrity - 128-EEA1/2/3. 
Which of them is used commercially and is most efficient in terms of speed/power usage?
And if 128-EIA2 (AES in CBC-MAC mode) is used for integrity doesnt this also acts as a cipher? I dont see reason for seperate ciphering algorithm.
Thanks!